# Electron loading html page as text in window

Tags: angular, electron

I am using angular and electron to create an app. When I build the app and run electron. The electron window shows the actual code of the target html page as text and not as an html page as it is supposed to be.

The screenshot of the electron app is:[image]

I have not been able to find this issue anywhere on the internet. My electron code for creating the window is:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({
    // fullscreen: true,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    },
    minimizable: true,
    closable: true,
    frame: false
  });

  win.setMenu(null);

  win.maximize();

  // load index.html from dist folder
  win.loadURL(
    url.format({
      pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/../../dist/inlabel/index.html'),
      protocol: "file:",
      slashes: true
    })
  );

  // open dev tools
  win.webContents.openDevTools();

  win.on("closed", () => {
    win = null
  })
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong

Comment: Is this code is inside your "createWindow" function and you are calling it like this: 
app.on('ready', createWindow); What version of electron?

Comment: Yes i am calling this inside createWindow function and app.on('ready', createWindow). Electron version is 4.0.7

Comment: The code you posted here does not expose this behavior. The cause must be somewhere else. Try recreating your project from scratch to find it.

Comment: when i run window.location.reload from dev tools. The normal html page gets loaded and app works fine.